# Move an app on Compute Engine to App Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I have an app running on Compute Engine. Now it's time, to move this app to App Engine.

Is there a checklist on what needs to be done regarding DNS and other configurations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no guide on this type of migration, but there are other resource you can use.
You should start by choosing if you want to use App Engine Standard or App Engine Flexible - you can find comparison [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments).
Then you can move to tutorials on deploying for [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart) and [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart) variants.
And since underlying infrastructure is the same for Compute and App Engine, most of the DNS-related config will be the same.